# perl - file test `-f` is not really working for unknown reasons

Tags: perl

in my `/tmp`, I have these files:

```
8ldocdDUY6
aoB6va72iV
config-err-3g5Pdc
....
```

All are empty: `ls /tmp  | perl -ne 'print "/tmp/$_"' | xargs file`
output:

```
8ldocdDUY : empty
aoB6va72iV: empty
config-err-3g5Pdc: empty
```

But if I do `ls /tmp  | perl -ne 'print if -f "/tmp/$_"'`, then no file. No output. Why so, when used `-f` test so that every plain file should be true?

However: If i do just one file test:
`perl -e 'print "yes" if -f "/tmp/8ldocdDUY6"'`, then it will print `yes`, so it is true. So why it isnt for the previous inline command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-l` command line flag in addition to the rest. It strips the new line characters from the `ls` output before feeding them to the one liner body. Otherwise the file names have extra new lines.

Comment: I always forgot to `chomp`, when parsing from `<>`, thanks

Comment: but still doesnt work to unlink: `ls /tmp | perl -nle 'unlink if -f "/tmp/$_"'`, I have to `unlink` without any test, like this: `ls /tmp | perl -nle 'unlink "/tmp/$_"'`, so it unlinks every file except of dirs (which is desired, but the wrong way). So how to unlink with file test?

Comment: unlink full file path. Otherwise by default it removes $_ which is just the base name.

Comment: also, enable warnings, even (especially?) on oneliners. adding -w would have given you `Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline`